# Difference between '#' and '*' character in the ubuntu configuration file

Tags: ubuntu, configuration

I am editing my **/etc/security/limits.conf** file and notice that there are three entries exists in the same file.

```
* soft     nproc          65535    
# root soft     nproc          65535    
root soft     nproc          65535
```

One entry that starts with '#' means, it is commented. The line that starts with out any special character is the one effecting the system.

Wondering what does `'*'` signifies at the start of the first line in the configuration file, is it a comment or actually affecting the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **'*'** in this case (and almost all Unix config files) means wildcard (i.e. all) of users/groups. Also note that for security limits, the user **root** is an exception.
If you want to set a limit for **root**, this field must contain the literal *root* word.

For more info you can run:

```
man limits.conf
```